# Is ajax the best/only way to add a jsonwebtoken (JWT) to a request header?

Tags: jwt

I have a simple multi-page site written in vanilla JS, Pug, and Node, that uses login with JWT. When a user logs in, the client is returned a JWT. The JWT is stored in `localStorage`. Now, when a user clicks a link to a protected route on a given page, I need to send the JWT to the server so it can authenticate that the JWT is valid (i.e., user is logged in).

I understand I can do something like this for a given protected route:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/protected",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + <token>
    }
    success: (res) => {
      if (res.status == 200) {
        window.location.replace("/profile");
      }
      else {
        window.location.replace("/login");
      }
    },
    error: (err) => { console.log(err) }
  });
```

It seems like a lot of overhead for a simple link click. Is this the recommended method of adding a JWT to a request header or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pretty much this is the only way. But to simplify your things you can create a wrapper on above `ajax` method and use that function for protected routes.

```
function authAjax(url, method, successCallback, errorCallback){
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: method,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + <token>
    }
    success: (res) => {
      if (res.status == 200) {
        successCallback(res)
      }
      else {
        window.location.replace("/login");
      }
    },
    error: (err) => {
      console.log(err) 
      errorCallback(err)
    }
  });
}
```

And use this like:

```
authAjax('/protected', 'GET', (data) => {
  console.log('API res', data)
}, (err) => {
  alert('Sorry, Something went wrong :(')
})
```